# Incorrect syntax near ',' . It is not underligned, it just doesn't want to execute-sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE Log_Table (
    ISBN VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Book_Title VARCHAR(50), 
    Author VARCHAR(50),
    Publication_Year INT,
    Category_ID INT,
    No_of_Copies_Actual INT,
    No_of_Copies_Current INT,
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate   DATETIME
)
Go
CREATE TRIGGER Log_Table ON Book_Mst FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE AS

DECLARE @NOW DATETIME
SET @NOW = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

UPDATE Log_Table
   SET EndDate = @now
  FROM Log_Table, DELETED
 WHERE Log_Table.ISBN = DELETED.ISBN
   AND Log_Table.EndDate IS NULL

INSERT INTO Log_Table (ISBN,Book_Title,Author,Publication_Year,Category_ID,No_of_Copies_Actual,No_of_Copies_Current, StartDate, EndDate)
SELECT (ISBN, Book_Title, Author, Publication_Year, Category_ID, No_of_Copies_Actual, No_of_Copies_Current, @NOW, NULL)
  FROM INSERTED
```

Comment: did you try slicing/dicing this into smaller statements to figure out which part of all this is actually causing the error?

Comment: Just remove your brackets around that `SELECT`. The problem is you are bunching those all together as 1 column which does not work.

Comment: Your Trigger Name and table name are same `Log_Table `

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `(...)` brackets that are surrouding the `SELECT`

i.e.

```
INSERT INTO Log_Table (ISBN,Book_Title,Author,Publication_Year,Category_ID,No_of_Copies_Actual,No_of_Copies_Current, StartDate, EndDate)
SELECT ISBN, Book_Title, Author, Publication_Year, Category_ID, No_of_Copies_Actual, No_of_Copies_Current, @NOW, NULL
  FROM INSERTED
```

Comment: I removed the brackets but still the trigger doesnt execute.

Comment: That's a new problem ;) The incorrect syntax error was from the brackets `(....)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the parentheses from your `SELECT` statement; this is probably what is causing your syntax error.